# DIV with CSS resize attribute detectable in Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

A DIV can be resize using CSS like this

```
resize: both;
overflow: auto;
```

So, when you mouse over the DIV , you will get the resize cursor on the lower right corner.

I tried to detect the cursor change to "resize" in Java Script with no luck so far. I tried to log the cursor style with this code on a "click event" when the cursor change to "resize" like this:

```
console.log(document.body.style.cursor);
console.log(e.target.style.cursor);
```

The log result id always a " " (empty) instead of a "resize" value.

Thanks  in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I checked, string is empty for `e.target.style.cursor`. So I propose to solve the issue with a hack. We know, that an area where cursor changes is about 18×18 pixels, so we should detect cursor at this zone.

```
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
const deltaX = 18;
const deltaY = 18;

const detectionOfCursorInLowerRightCorner = (e) => {
  const rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = e.clientX; // Position X of cursor relative to the document.
  const y = e.clientY; // Position Y of cursor relative to the document.

  // Calculate lower and high edges of the area where cursor changes.
  const lowEdgeX = rect.width - deltaX;
  const highEdgeX = rect.width;

  const lowEdgeY = rect.height - deltaY;
  const highEdgeY = rect.height;

  const elementCursorX = x - rect.x; // Position X of cursor relative to the element.
  const elementCursorY = y - rect.y; // Position Y of cursor relative to the element.

  console.log(' ');
  console.log(elementCursorX, elementCursorY);

  if (elementCursorX > lowEdgeX && elementCursorX <= highEdgeX && elementCursorY > lowEdgeY && elementCursorY <= highEdgeY) {
    console.log('here'); // Cursor is in the area.
  }
};

textarea.addEventListener('mousemove', detectionOfCursorInLowerRightCorner);
```

Do not forget do `textarea.removeEventListener('mousemove', detectionOfCursorInLowerRightCorner)` on element destroy. And define your own CSS class to detect when textarea has properties `resize: both;` and `overflow: auto;`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. Indeed, I did something approximative (I skipped the Y axis logic) similar to your solution. On mousemove in the DIV, I consider that resize will occurs if my mouse X position is between the offetWidth-15px and offsetx. If not, I can drag my DIV.

I considered also the resize observer feature, but it was getting too complicated for multiple DIV elements.

The idea is to be add drag/resize events to my DIV elements for editing purpose over a canvas using absolute positioning.

Congratulation for your concise and well formatted answer and the time spent you spent on it.